# Google Cloud Datastore showing up as compute engine in usage reports

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore, google-cloud-datastore

I have been using datastore for some weeks now and can't see any record of it in the [usage reports](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED), but i do have lots of "Compute Engine API" items. I am not running App Engine, i have my server on Digital Ocean. Is this because datastore runs on a compute instance so needs to spin one up to work? Is there a way to use Datastore without App Engine or Compute Engine? Or is there at least a way to see my datastore usages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Google's [datastore pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing), you won't be charged for datastore usage until you go over the free quota, the free daily limit it in the link posted below. So my guess is you might not have used up your free quota.

The quota usage is on the app engine quota details page as state in the documentation - 
"To see your application's Cloud Datastore usage, including quota consumption, visit the [App Engine Quota Details](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/quotadetails?_ga=2.4258224.-247142741.1481523677) page. You'll need to do this even if your application does not run in App Engine."